# Find a project or plug-in in Ecilpse workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

So I have nearly 300 plug-ins and features in my workspace at any given time. And I want to quickly filter the Package Explorer view, to show only projects that have, say, *xyz* in their name. Is there a way to do this?

I can't seem to find a way to search for projects specifically in the search dialogs either. I feel this should be straightforward but can't seem to recall how to do it right now, if it was ever possible.

Using eclipse 4.4.2, on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this custom package explorer [plugin](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/07/31/eclipse-papercut-9-filtered-packageexplorer-by-project-name/). Here you can filter resources.

Comment: The update site mentioned doesn't work, probably an old link now.

Comment: Read all comments. Source is here https://github.com/vogella/jdt-package-explorer/ you can build this plugin locally on your machine.Contact author for update site problem.

Comment: That's certainly a lot of hassle, but I will try it out in free time. It does look like its pretty old so might not easily work out of the box. Nevertheless this seems to be the only answer to this so far.